# Rounding dataframe columns based on condition with for loop

Tags: pandas, dataframe, rounding

I have multiindex like this:

```
                            Capacity\nMWh  Day-Ahead\nMWh  Intraday\nMWh  UEVM\nMWh  ...  Cost Per. MW\n(with Imp.)\n$/MWh  Cost Per. MW\n(w/o Imp.)\n$/MWh  Intraday\nMape  Day-Ahead\nMape
Power Plants Date                                                                     ...
POWERP12     2020 January             4.00         1416.83        1135.76     875.97  ...                          0.968230                         1.326735        0.206331         0.280242
             2020 February            4.00          567.02         564.40     647.81  ...                          0.530140                         0.552554        0.138958         0.144021
             2020 March               0.00            0.00           0.00       0.00  ...                          0.000000                         0.000000        0.000000         0.000000
             2020 April               0.00            0.00           0.00       0.00  ...                          0.000000                         0.000000        0.000000         0.000000
```

I am trying to create a function which rounds the columns based on specific word or character or somethig in the column name. Here is my function:

```
def column_rounder(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        if '\nMWH' in col: # Here is my condition, I want to find column name which contains '\nMWh'.
            df[col] = df[col].round(0)
    return df
```

Unfortunately, I can not modify the dataframe in the for loop, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
def round(col):
    col = col+1
    return col

for col in df:
    df[col] = round(df[col])
```